# xe:restService takes 28 seconds to call bean

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I have this REST service XPage in Domino 10.0 RHEL 7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" rendered="false">
        <xe:restService id="restService" pathInfo="VCard" state="false">
                <xe:this.service>
                        <xe:customRestService contentType="application/json"
                                serviceBean="net.my.rest.VCardService">
                        </xe:customRestService>
                </xe:this.service>
        </xe:restService>
</xp:view>
```

When I call the REST API then `beforePageLoad` and `afterPageLoad` events fire immediately (I checked this by having a `print` statement in events). But then it always takes **28 seconds** before the bean is called. Here is the `renderService` method in `VCardService`:

```
@Override
public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {
    System.out.println("VCard renderService");
    request = engine.getHttpRequest();
    response = engine.getHttpResponse();
    renderService();
}
```

I get this "VCard renderService" to the log 28 seconds after `afterPageLoad` event in XPage. What is causing this delay?

One thing I thought about: should I define VCardService as bean in faces-config.xml? The REST API examples I've seen don't mention that.

**Update 1:**

> A service bean is not a managed bean, so you don't need to specify
>   anything in your faces-config.xml.

https://www.wissel.net/blog/2014/10/custom-rest-service-in-xpages-using-a-service-bean.html

**Update 2:**

I tested with a very simple, basically empty service class and there is no delay. The vCard service is using about 10 mainly JSON related JARs stored in NSF Code/Jars section. Looks like it is spending a lot of time to load those JARs every time the bean is called. I will next try to upgrade the ODS of NSF from 43 to 53 and if that does not help then place the JARs to server folder.

**Update 3:**

ODS upgraded to 53 (R10) and that did not help. The slowness disappears for a few hours after the API is used the first time which is typical XPage behavior.

**Update 4:**

Removed the JARs from NSF and placed them to server /lib/ext folder, that did not help either.

Comment: Does it only take 28 seconds the first time the service is called - or every time?

Comment: Good point! I was developing and building it so for me it was every time. But now I tried multiple times and only the first time was slow. But my experience with XPages is that it will get unloaded in few hours and then again there will be this additional 28 seconds to execution time which is too much. I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: You could try to build the actual service using a fatJar so you only need to locate one file

Comment: As I expected it was slow again om first time this morning. Sometimes I've even created a poller which keeps the XPages alive. @stwissel that's something I could try but is the time really spent in locating the JARs?

Comment: An experiment will show. AFAIK the JEE server doesn’t load jar from nsf but some clever mechanism moves them to a temp location first. Build a plugin. Safer option than file

Comment: Stephan is correct. Put the same jar in multiple NSFs and it will get detached for each nsf to xsp temp folders.